# Resistors on decoupling capacitors in ADC Layout Guidelines

Tags: pcb-design, analog, adc, noise

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8691.pdf) for TI's ADS8691 ADC chip has the following diagram in its layout guidelines. I just have a few questions about the resistors in the diagram, which I don't believe are mentioned anywhere (but are presumably common knowledge to an electrical engineer).

1. What is the purpose of the resistors in series with the
   ground-decoupling capacitors for the REFCAP and REFIO pins (4 and
   6)?
2. What is the purpose of the series resistors immediately after
   the capacitor on the analog input pins (the two directly below 5 and 6)? What about the next resistor immediately in series on the analog ground trace (why is it it not pointless)?
3. What is the purpose of the parallel resistors in the optional "Analog Input" section (does this have something to do with current-limiting the TVS diode?)---presumably something to do with the inductance of a big resistor?
4. Finally, if it isn't obvious from your explanations, what are reasonable choices for these resistances? (If input signal frequency really matters, please assume ~50Hz.)

[image: ADC layout guidelines]

Comment: Is there a schematic associated with this layout?

Comment: Since that layout disagrees with the manual schematic, I think it may be a mistake.  Also, having the REFGND pin with no DC connection to ground seems highly questionable to me.

Comment: @user1850479 By "manual schematic" are you referring to Figure 7-7 in the datasheet, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of the resistors in series with the
> ground-decoupling capacitors for the REFCAP and REFIO pins (4 and 6)?

The datasheet says the REFCAP is a "ADC reference buffer decoupling capacitor pin", I believe this is to force the REFCAP's capacitor ground to be refered back to the ground of the ADC (rather than some other point on the board) to reduce noise. A small voltage difference could exist on the PCB if the grounds of the caps were placed elsewhere and lead to error.

> What is the purpose of the series resistors immediately after the
> capacitor on the analog input pins (the two directly below 5 and 6)?
> What about the next resistor immediately in series on the analog
> ground trace (why is it it not pointless)?

Forms a differential input filter with the capacitor tied to pins 5 and 6. The second resistor in series is most likely to make minor adjustments with two resistors (ie 100 and 1 ohm resistors or 100 and 5 to make a total of 105 ohms, (not actual values just an example)).

Finally, if it isn't obvious from your explanations, what are reasonable choices for these resistances? (If input signal frequency really matters, please assume ~50Hz.)

> What is the purpose of the parallel resistors in the optional "Analog
> Input" section (does this have something to do with current-limiting
> the TVS diode?)---presumably something to do with the inductance of a
> big resistor?

Again it's for tuning or using one or the other if you want to test one size of resistor vs the other size.

> Finally, if it isn't obvious from your explanations, what are
> reasonable choices for these resistances? (If input signal frequency
> really matters, please assume ~50Hz.)

The resistors make and RC filter, the filter pole is the bandwidth of your analog input. For example: If your application needed DC to 1kHz then set the RC pole to 1kHz.

Here is more information on [RC common mode filters](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/afe-design-considerations-rtd-ratiometric.html) and how to set them

Comment: Notwithstanding the comment left by someone above that the suggested layout disagrees with the schematic in Figure 7-7 of the datasheet, I have found your answer very helpful. If I can just ask for some elaboration on the first question: what would happen if the resistors connected to pins 4 and 6 were shorted out?